# Understanding comma after の

Tags: particle-の, punctuation

A sentence from Kimi no na wa novel:

> そうだ。こういう時間帯の、呼び名があった。黄昏。

I might be overthinking but I am not sure about the comma after の. How would the meaning change if it is just "こういう時間帯の呼び名があった" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expresses a pause in internal speech, and just means the same as こういう時間帯の呼び名があった=*there was a name for such a time (of the day)*.